# Retrieve Current Active Directory User Details C# Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm trying to get the current active directory details of a user via a Web API wrote in C#. I'm unsure of what to do, I have been tasked this by work and I don't know C#. I'm trying to write it in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: What research have you done? Have you tried googling your question to see what will come up?

Comment: @Chillie yeah i have tried to google the most i can come up with is that its possible ive had no correct answers that worked for me

Comment: Please explain better what the setup actually looks like. Are you trying to connect a ASP.net or PHP site to the Web Api? What in data does the Web Api already know ( are you sending it the NT username)?

Comment: @Chillie I am trying to link my react js site to the ASP.NET version 4.5.2 api, i am able to get it to return a string but i am unable to get it to return the current user details from active directory, I am trying to return it so that i can log the user in using them details, removing the option for them to login themselves making their life easier

Comment: If this is a Windows Authentication Web API, you should be able to create a new Web API in Visual Studio based off the Windows Auth. template.

Comment: @Chillie I have done that but it still doesn't work I can't return the user via the api

Comment: @Chillie I can get it to return my user if i connect via the localhost/testwebapi/api/values but when i call that from my react js app it says im not authorized to access that even though i am doing it from the same machine, how would i do that via react js

Comment: It sounds more like you need a question asking what is wrong with your code. LDAP and AD can be fickle. If you aren't connecting to it just right, going into the correct group or OU, it won't work.

Comment: @Chillie right ok so i need some sort of npm addon for react that will allow me to do LDAP connections or something along them lines

Comment: You can do it through .NetCore or the full stack. It can be pretty simple, but if you don't know what you're doing, then it isn't so simple.

Comment: I have moved from using core to using version 4.5.2 as I couldn't get help for core as the rest of the guys in the office know 4.5.2 but non of us can work out how to do this, any tutorials would be great.

Comment: @Chillie How would you go about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This LDAP tutorial is old, but should still be helpful. I recently used it to create a CRUD Web API for Active Directory. https://www.codeproject.com/articles/90142/everything-in-active-directory-via-c-net-using

I would give you more than just a link, but there is a bit of code, and I would rather not just copy and past it.